# Making Visual Studio 2019 see the git repo present in source but not in the build dir (which has the sln file)

Tags: git, visual-studio, cmake

I'm working on an existing, large open-source project that doesn't like in-source-tree builds. So its cmake-generated `.sln` file is placed in the build dir that has no `.git` anywhere in its parent directories because that `.git` is in the disjoint source tree.

```
\build
  \proj.sln
\src
  \.git
```

How do I make Visual Studio 2019 still see these "sideways" .git files? It can see the (C++ etc.) sources referred in the sln, of course, but nothing relating to git works inside VS2019 in this setup, by default.

[image]

I'm guessing I could mess with [GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499560/3588161) but I'm not sure it that would work with the way VS does git.

(And yes, the `src` dir is a git-cloned repo. I've made commits in it etc., but from the command line.)

And if I F1 (for help) the "Git Global Settings" in VS 2019... it goes to an [oops page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/not-in-toc/default?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(keywords_removed)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2022) so that isn't exactly helpful. Ok, I found the [actual VS doc/help for git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-settings?view=vs-2019). But it doesn't really answer my question.

If instead of opening the sln file, I open the directory of the source (`src`) from VS, then VS sees the git repo ok (current branch and what not) ... but I can't build anything, because VS can't see/find the sln file in this context. So, how do I "have my cake and eat it", i.e. have VS see the git stuff and allow me to build?

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263564/3588161) MS just doesn't do true out-of-source builds in/with their toolset.

Comment: For anybody wondering, I found a partial workaround for this by using VS for the sln and build, but VScode (opening the folder/files) for VS-style git version control, from within an editor. Both VScode and VS inssta-reload changes made by the other to files, by default. It's a bit cumbersome to have to work like this though, with two editors/IDEs, so I'm still looking for a one-IDE alternative.  Also, support for building from VScode is pretty scant, amusingly for MS C++ projects (it's better for C#). I only found the fairly obscure sterin.msbuild-tools for generic msbuild to do C++ ones.

Answer (score 4):

I've made VS see the git repo (from within the sln) by manually adding a `.git` file in the build directory with just this contents:

```
gitdir: X:/full-path-to-repo/.git/worktrees/src
```

I had forgotten to mention that the src was also a worktree, but that probably didn't make a diff (they also have .git file).

Unlike the GIT_DIR environment variable, this `.git`-file method of telling where there repo is, isn't ignored by VS's git implementation.

**But there's a big problem with this** (too)! VS now thinks it should add all those build object files to the repo! It thinks there are some 4,000 A-type changes :-( So, for this to be a real solution, I'd also need to able to tell it not do that somehow. (This might be ok for a smaller project, but writing filters for all those cmake-made files is going to be challenge in my case...)

[image]

[image]

---

Also, for an alternative approach if I install the cmake workload in VS and open the source folder again (instead of the sln), VS makes a big mess by immediately trying to do an in-source build (in an `src\out` subdir it created), and with completely wrong, auto-generated settings, like using Ninja for some reason when this project doesn't use it at all. (I suspect it did this because it could not find the out-of-source build dir, which had the right cmake cache.)

[image]

So it seems there are "miles to go" for VS to be fully useable with cmake projects like this, meaning that use out-of-source-tree build dirs. [Apparently](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/cmake-for-visual-studio-developers/) nothing really changed in the MS cmake approach in 8 years:

> - It works in the context of Visual Studio’s new “Open Folder” feature rather than their established project/solution workspace. So you will have to learn the new environment.
> - There are additional settings files to override CMake configuration which will be a source of duplication and confusion.
> - It used the Ninja build system by default. To change it to VS projects, you have to adjust it in a settings file.
> - To launch the debugger for startup executable, you have to introduce a launch file.

Comment: Since VS2019 it's passible to open a cmake *cache* in VS, I'm gonna have to try that! It's only really documented on a MSFT blog though https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/open-existing-cmake-caches-in-visual-studio/ I'm skeptical that will find the git file though, because it would be in the same situation/location as opening the sln file. So while MSFT may have made some progress on cmake usability (from within VS), it might not help with my VS-git problem...

Comment: Oh, and open-cmake-cache doesn't work with cmake 3.20+ because it relied on the now-removed cmake-server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-160#open-an-existing-cache

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try and launch Visual Studio from a CMD where you type first:

```
set GIT_DIR=C:\path\to\.git
cd C:\path\to\proj
.\proj.sln
```

(assuming the `.sln` extension is associated with `devenv.exe`)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does nothing. VS's git thing seems to ignore `GIT_DIR`.

Comment: @Fizz That is what I feared, but it was worth a shot.